# Python 3 Help on programing

Tags: python-3.x

Goal: Create a program that will prompt the user for the total cost of a meal. it will then ask them if ht service was good.

if the user responds with positive response yes or no, then the program will computer how much 20% tip would be and then output its along with a new total including tip.

should the user type something other than an expected positive response, it should only calculate a 10% tip and display it.

So far I have the code below but am stuck at displaying the output phrase and the newly computed costs.

```py
x = float(input("What was the total cost of your meal today?"))
service = input("Was your service good today? yes or no.")

if (service == "yes"):
    print("Your total tip today is" + (x * .20))
    
else:
    print("Your total today is" + (x * .10))
```

Comment: Just a hint: you correctly casted a `str` to a `float` in `x = float(input("...")`. Then check the error message you get from your `print("..." + ...)` statements, it's pretty explicit :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are trying to merge string and non-string value, in this case it's `x*.10`.
In this answer, i have used the formative strings, which will let you to use both strings value and integer value in one string (surround the non strings value with curly brackets).

```
x = float(input("What was the total cost of your meal today? "))
service = input("Was your service good today? yes or no: ")
if service == "yes":
    print(f"Your total tip today is {x * .20}")
else:
    print(f"Your total today is {x * .10}")
```

Also remember to use proper indexing.